Getting weird error in Vue.js 3 while using i18n
I am working on a project where i18n is used, and the loader is '@intlify/vue-i18n-loader'. I am working with 2 languages: English and German. I am getting a weird error while running the app.
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                  2:59:59 PM

 error  in ./src/locales/de.json

Module parse failed: Cannot parse JSON: Unexpected token 'e', "export def"... is not valid JSON while parsing 'export default {
  "bch": {
    "bps": ('
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@intlify/vue-i18n-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: Cannot parse JSON: Unexpected token 'e', "export def"... is not valid JSON while parsing 'export default {
  "bch": {
    "bps": ('
    at JsonParser.parse (/Users/mohitchandel/Documents/front-end/node_modules/webpack/lib/json/JsonParser.js:54:10)

The weird thing is that I have never exported the JSON file mentioned in the Error and the file is in pure JSON format.
Here is my vue.config.js
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require("circular-dependency-plugin");
const ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin = require("replace-in-file-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require("./package.json").version;

module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.optimization.minimizer("terser").tap((args) => {
            args[0].terserOptions.output = {
                ...args[0].terserOptions.output,
                comments: false, // exclude all comments from output
                ascii_only: true,
            };
            return args;
        });
        config.module
            .rule("i18n")
            .test(/\.json$/)
            .include.add(path.resolve(__dirname, "src/locales"))
            .end()
            .use("@intlify/vue-i18n-loader")
            .loader("@intlify/vue-i18n-loader")
            .end();
    },
    pluginOptions: {
        webpackBundleAnalyzer: {
            analyzerMode: process.env.VUE_APP_MODE === "production" ? "disabled" : "static",
            openAnalyzer: false,
        },
        i18n: {
            locale: "en",
            fallbackLocale: "en",
            localeDir: "locales",
            enableInSFC: true,
        },
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
            },
            fallback: {
                stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
                assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
                http: require.resolve("stream-http"),
                https: require.resolve("https-browserify"),
                os: require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"),
                url: require.resolve("url/"),
            },
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/date\-fns[\/\\]/, new RegExp(`[/\\\\\](en|de)[/\\\\\]index\.js$`)),
            new CircularDependencyPlugin({
                exclude: /a\.js|node_modules/,
                failOnError: true,
                allowAsyncCycles: false,
                cwd: process.cwd(),
            }),
            new ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin([
                {
                    dir: "dist/static/img",
                    files: ["sheet.json", "sheet_holiday.json"],
                    rules: [
                        {
                            search: '"image": "sheet.png"',
                            replace: '"image": "sheet.png?v=' + process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION + '"',
                        },
                        {
                            search: '"image": "characters.png"',
                            replace: '"image": "characters.png?v=' + process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION + '"',
                        },
                        {
                            search: '"image": "mall.png"',
                            replace: '"image": "mall.png?v=' + process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION + '"',
                        },
                        {
                            search: '"image": "sheet_holiday.png"',
                            replace: '"image": "sheet_holiday.png?v=' + process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION + '"',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ]),
        ],
    },
    publicPath: "/",
    outputDir: "dist",
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    assetsDir: "static",
    productionSourceMap: false,
};

And here is my de.json
{
    "bch": {
        "bps": "Bytes pro Sekunde",
        "ctps": "{'@'}:btc.ctps",
        "difficulty": "{'@'}:btc.difficulty",
        "fiatPrice-usd": "{'@'}:btc.fiatPrice-usd",
        "halving": "{'@'}:btc.halving",
    },
    ....
}

